# JPA Concurrent Transaction Strategies

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, concurrency

I am working on a warehouse management system, using JPA 2.0 - EclipseLink and I have come across the need to implement concurrent transactions, currently I am implementing a timestamp difference to validate the last time the quantities are altered: added, removed, transferred.

This strategy seems a bit flawed, and requires a lot of manual verification's, that may create bugs, are there alternative methods of doing this that are provided by the JPA framework?

Comment: Does optimistic locking not work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand you are trying to implement an optimistic locking strategy with timestamps.

JPA provides out of the box an optimistic locking mechanism with the help of a version field. Basically you have a version field (`short`, `int`, `long` or `Timestamp`) in your entities that is incremented/set on every modification of the entity.

If an entity has a different version at save time than the version it had at load time an `OptimisticLockingException` is thrown meaning that another user/thread modified the entity in between. You can catch this exception and decide what do:

- tell the user that saved second to restart its modification
- merge the modifications (if possible)
- overwrite

It depends on the usecase.

See also: oracle [javaee 6 tutorial on optimistic locking](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkjhz.html#gkjjc)

Comment: That is exaclty what I was looking for, I have two views of Origin and Destiny Products, and these can get updated by concurrent users, if that happens a warning is lauched and the user has to restart the transfer operation. I will replace my implementation with the one provided by JPA. Many Thanks!

Comment: Well you might not always be able to catch `OptimisticLockingException`. There's a possibility the bean is managed by a container, or has a remote interface. You might just get a container-initiated ÈJBException`, perhaps not even wrapped around the origin. All that is required by the container is to _log_ `OptimisticLockingException`. If you need this fine grained control, make sure you call the method `EntityManager#flush` in a try/catch block at the end of your business logic. If locking fails, you'll catch the `OptimisticLockingException` for sure and can do whatever you like with it.